# Elasticsearch filtering with date range data and a must_not bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to extract the following sql query to elasticsearch.

```
Select * 
from someTable
Where @timestamp < some_date and @timestamp >= some_other_date
and dst != '-'
```

And then do some aggregations on the returned documents. The aggregations part I have figured it out, and works perfectly. But I don't get the documents filtered properly. I tried the following query but I  get doc's with dst = '-' which are in turns computed in the aggregations.

The query

```
"query": {                              
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "term": {
                "dst": '-'
            }
        }, 
        "filter":{
            "range":{
                "@timestamp":{
                    "gte":"a date",
                    "lt": "another date"
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Am I doing something wrong. I set the size to 0 because I am using aggregations (not shown in here).  Elasticsearch ver2.4 and python elasticsearch library.

I know it's not working because the aggregations results contain values from documents that dst is '-"

Comment: How are you sending your query? Also what is the mapping of your `dst` field?

Comment: sending the query via the python elasticsearch client with an aggregations query. the dst field is analzyed. Could that be the fault? Is the logic of the query correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This field should not be analyzed, as it analyzer removes - char from field in index.

If you need this field to be analyzed for an other reason use multi-fields.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: I had a feeling this was the problem? Is the query correct? Does it correspond to the SQL query written on my post?

Comment: If you fix index mapping with not_analyzed it should work.